# Momentum operator derivation in QFT from QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum

In David Tong`s [QFT notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) there is a chapter about the derivation of the momentum operator from quantum mechanics (page 44) where he is showing that the momentum operator can be expressed by the spatial derivative, i. e. $$P |\phi\rangle= \int {\rm d}^3 x \left(-i \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)|\vec x\rangle.$$

To arrive at equation 2.122 he then makes the step 
$$\begin{align}
P |\phi\rangle &= \int \frac{{\rm d}^3 x \,{\rm d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}  a^\dagger \left(i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{-i\vec p \vec x}\right) \phi({\vec {x}})|0\rangle\\ &= 
\int \frac{{\rm d}^3 x \,{\rm d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}   e^{-i\vec p \vec x}\left(-i \frac{\partial \phi({\vec {x}})}{\partial x} \right) a^\dagger|0\rangle
\end{align}$$
 which is not really clear to me. Can anyone help to see what happened there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is just an integration by parts considering that boundary terms vanish.

Comment: why would the boundary terms vanish here?

Comment: You are integrating over all space. You can assume that the field vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Hi @A.Feynman; Welcome to Phys. SE. It would be much better if you add a little more context to your answer.